# knowing wrap and encrypt

Tags: pkcs#11

what is the diffrence between wrap and encrypt in pkcs11? I think both work similar.Is it right that wrap only needs a handle for a key while encrypt needs a key for encryption???

Answer (score 0):

Encryption is about data, wrap about keys.
When you wrap a key, you **export** it **encrypted** under another key (symmetric or asymmetric key), which you specify in the wrap operation through a handle.
After the wrap, you don't get a handle, but the key itself (i.e. encoded data).